# Why is my Ubuntu being slow

Tags: virtualization, ram, system-requirements

I am seeing if I like Ubuntu on a virtual computer program. I can only give it 3 GB of ram. It was a bit slow when I used it. Will it speed up if I use 4 GB of ram.

Comment: It is unlikely. Virtual system is always slower than a real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortuntately, RAM doesn't impact speed or performance until you're running a lot of applications/programs. It might have to do with the program you're using, or your computer in general.

I don't think giving it more RAM will help, but you can definitely try and see if it works.